# Dynamically generate bootstrap Modal in AJAX in Modal I'm trying to use AutoNumeric 4.6 but this not work (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use https://makitweb.com/dynamically-load-content-in-bootstrap-modal-with-ajax/ in my project.

I'm trying to use Autonumeric 4.6 in input type text in Ajax generate bootstrap modal.

I added AutoNumeric script in general html file, php file and nothing.
Script working but not AJAX generate modal.

Please Help

My code:

HTML

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="empModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Current Money</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.CurrentMoney').click(function(){

            var CurrentMoney= $(this).data('id');

            $.ajax({
                url: '../Server-Side/CurrentMoney.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {CurrentMoney: CurrentMoney},
                success: function(response){
                    // Add response in Modal body
                    $('.modal-body').html(response);
                    // Display Modal
                    $('#empModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

CurrentMoney.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['CurrentMoney']))
{

$response = '<input type="text" class="AutoNumeric">';
        echo $response;
    

}
else {
    $response = 'Error';
    echo $response;

}

exit;

?>
```

AutoNumeric library

```
<!-- autonumeric4 -->
<script src="../plugins/autoNumeric/src/autonumeric4.6.js"></script>

<script>

    const autoNumericOptionsEuro = {
        digitGroupSeparator        : ' ',
        allowDecimalPadding: false
    };

    new AutoNumeric('.AutoNumeric', autoNumericOptionsEuro);

</script>
```

JSFiddle - Code
https://jsfiddle.net/Fox21/ht1kyuvw/3/

Answer (score 0):

call AutoNumeric library after ajax call done

somthing like

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('.CurrentMoney').click(function(){

        var CurrentMoney= $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '../Server-Side/CurrentMoney.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {CurrentMoney: CurrentMoney},
            success: function(response){
                // Add response in Modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(response);
                // Display Modal
                $('#empModal').modal('show');
               
                 
const autoNumericOptionsEuro = {
    digitGroupSeparator        : ' ',
    allowDecimalPadding: false
};

new AutoNumeric('.AutoNumeric', autoNumericOptionsEuro);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying use Your solution but still not working
I think that generate modal not sees jquery library
Debugger reports no errors

Comment: I add JSFiddle Code.